# How to set several state at the same time with useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to combine several states and handle them at the same time with `useState` hook, check the following example which updates some text on user input:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const initialState = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25
  };
  const [{name, age}, setFormState] = useState(initialState);
  const handleNameChange = (e) => {
    setFormState({
      name: e.target.value,
      age
    });
  };
  const handleAgeChange = (e) => {
    setFormState({
      name,
      age: e.target.value
    })
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e=>e.preventDefault()}>
      <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
                <p>The person's name is {name}.</p>
                <br />
                <label htmlFor='age'>Age: </label>
                <input type='text' id='age' name='age' placeholder={age} onChange={handleAgeChange} />
                <p>His/her age is {age}.</p>
    </form>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

The code works well, but as you can see I'm using 2 functions to handle name and age separately., which was against my intention to save some code. Is it possible to just use 1 function to change name and age separately? Tried this but obviously it would update both with the same value.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const initialState = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25
  };
  const [{name, age}, setFormState] = useState(initialState);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormState({
      name: e.target.value,
      age: e.target.value
    });
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e=>e.preventDefault()}>
      <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder={name} onChange={handleChange} />
                <p>The person's name is {name}.</p>
                <br />
                <label htmlFor='age'>Age: </label>
                <input type='text' id='age' name='age' placeholder={age} onChange={handleChange} />
                <p>His/her age is {age}.</p>
    </form>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to set several different states at the same time with a single useState hook. You can either set them separately,
example:

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

or put all of the states into an object, and update that object using the useState hook.
Source: https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/
Example:

```
const [form, setState] = useState({
  username: '',
  password: ''
});

const updateField = e => {
    setState({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

return (
    <form onSubmit={printValues}>
      <label>
        Username:
        <input
          value={form.username}
          name="username"
          onChange={updateField}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Password:
        <input
          value={form.password}
          name="password"
          type="password"
          onChange={updateField}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
```

Comment: Your second solution seems to set several different states  at the same time with a single useState hook?

Comment: In the sense, that all the states are a single object's properties, yes you could say that @thinkvantagedu

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options to get your intended effect.

You could, for example, make a single function factory.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const initialState = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25
  };
  const [{name, age}, setFormState] = useState(initialState);
  const handleChange = key => e => {
    const newValue = e.target.value
    setFormState(oldState => ({
      ...oldState,
      [key]: newValue
    }));
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e=>e.preventDefault()}>
      <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder={name} onChange={handleChange('name')} />
                <p>The person's name is {name}.</p>
                <br />
                <label htmlFor='age'>Age: </label>
                <input type='text' id='age' name='age' placeholder={age} onChange={handleChange('age')} />
                <p>His/her age is {age}.</p>
    </form>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Alternatively, if you need a function factory with more flexibility (e.g. if you were trying to store other state in there), you could use useReducer() instead of useState(), then curry the dispatch function. As a rough, untested example

```
const reducer = (state, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'name': return {...state, name: payload}
    case 'age': return {...state, age: payload}
    default: throw new Error()
  }
}

const [{name, age}, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { name: 'john', age: 25 })
const makeEventListener = type => e => dispatch({type, payload: e.target.value})
// Now, you can use either use makeEventListener, or dispatch() directly
return <input type="text" value={name} onChange={makeEventListener('name'))
```

Lastly, it *is* possible to do exactly what you're saying, have one function that'll just update the state no matter who called it, by using of refs. But this is not a recommended approach.